# TextView.setTextSize behaves abnormally - How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens

Tags: android, textview

Calling `TextView.setTextSize()` is working abnormally. Right after the call to `setTextSize` if we get a `getTextSize` its returning a much higher value that what we set it to earlier.

Here's what we're doing:

```
zoomControl.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        float size = mViewShabad.getTextSize() + 1;
        textView.setTextSize(size);
    }
});
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: You are getting and setting the text size on two different objects?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

The difference here is that in the `setTextSize(int size)` method, the unit type by default is "sp" or "scaled pixels". This value will be a different pixel dimension for each screen density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi).

`getTextSize()`, on the other hand, returns the actual pixel dimensions of the text.

You can use `setTextSize(int unit, float size)` to specify a unit type. The constant values for this can be found in the TypedValue class, but some of them are:

```
TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX   //Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP   //Scaled Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP  //Device Independent Pixels
```

Comment: I just found that and was about to post it here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! :) It was good for me to learn too, haha. Strange there's no way to return different values, but I'm sure it's an easy conversion if I looked into it.

Comment: I think it should actually by TypedValue (singular). The import is android.util.TypedValue;

Comment: Also to note, it only started doing this at API level 7. Another "gotcha" in a ridiculous API.

Comment: Important to watch out for the argument order - I accidentally had setTextSize(size, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP) because that was the order I mistakenly presumed!

Comment: @MarkCarter Heh, I did the same thing one time and debugged it for an hour or two before realizing... >.>

Comment: Interestingly, on ICS on my Galaxy Nexus, using setTextSize(14, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP) made no effect (so used default size), but when I upgraded to Jelly Bean, none of the text was displayed (like 0 size). I was just about to report a Jelly Bean bug when I realised my mistake!

Comment: An inconsistency to watch out for is that in setting text size in paint objects, e.g. paintText.setTextSize(size), the default is actual pixel size, so you have to use paintText.setTextSize(size*dpi).

Answer (score 21):

this problem happend because the `getTextSize()` method return the size in pixels depend on screen density ! to get the Actual TextSize use this :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics;
metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float Textsize =myTextView.getTextSize()/metrics.density;
myTextView.setTextSize(Textsize+1);
```

i hope it solve it :)

Comment: I solved my problem by using display metrics with `setTextSize(int unit, float size)`。

Answer (score 8):

if Setting  change font size，something cause show error，you can do as：

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15.f);
```

Comment: Who sets textSize in `DIP`?

Answer (score 6):

When we try to setText() programmitically problem with getTextSize(), returns value in px instead of sp/dp/dip and we know 1sp/dp=1.5px(screen size =240).

```
 titleBar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size)*1.5f));
```

is working perfectly for me or we can use displaymatrix to px:sp/dp ratio then replace that value with 1.5f

```
means-> titleBar.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size)*your_sp_and_px_ratio_in_int f));
```

Answer (score 6):

After long time struck this and finally solved like this

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
          getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

create dimen folder like this res/values/dimensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>

 </resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

In short, if you want to zoom out your textsize

```
float size = mViewShabad.getTextSize()*1.1f;
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```

Because getTextSize() return UNIT_PX, then we should use UNIT_PX

Answer (score 3):

### Kotlin Solution

To set using a resource, just use this:

```
textView.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textView.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.my_text_size))
```

To do the same with a resource value, add this extension property to much more easily set your text size

```
textView.textSizeRes = R.dimen.my_text_size

var TextView.textSizeRes
    get() = textSize.toInt()
    set(@DimenRes textSizeRes) {
        setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, resources.getDimension(textSizeRes))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some extra flavor for this answer, as also ran into a bit of confusion. You *should* be able to drop this test into any `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` test you have in your project (you'll also need to add the dimens to your dimens.xml).

*Note: All these tests pass*

```
@Test public void testScaledFontSizes() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    final Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.fontScale = 2.0f;
    configuration.densityDpi = 160; // mdpi, 1:1
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);

    float scaledTextSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_15);
    assertEquals(30.0f, scaledTextSize);

    // Create a new TextView with the explicitly set configuration
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, scaledTextSize);

    // 30, because font size is scaled
    assertEquals(30.0f, textView.getTextSize());

    // This is what we *don't* want, it's scaled *twice*!
    textView.setTextSize(scaledTextSize);
    assertEquals(60.0f, textView.getTextSize());

    // DP instead of SP tests
    float fifteenDp = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp_15);
    assertEquals(15.0f, fifteenDp);

    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, fifteenDp);
    // Still 15, because it's DP, not SP
    assertEquals(15.0f, fifteenDp);

    textView.setTextSize(fifteenDp);
    // 30, because setTextSize DOES font scaling
    assertEquals(30.0f, textView.getTextSize());
  }
}
```

The big takeaway I found is that `TextView.setTextSize(float)` *applies the font scaling*, so if you pass in a dimen thats already labelled as SP instead of DP, then it will receive the font scaling *twice*.

Answer (score 0):

### Font size based on the screen size

```
public static void applyFont(TextView tv, Float fontSize) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, fontSize * fontFactor);
}

public static float fetchFontFactor(Activity act) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    act.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    float returnFactor = ((float) displayMetrics.widthPixels ) / 1280.0f;

    return returnFactor;
}
```

In MainActiviy.java I have

```
fontFactor = fetchFontFactor(this);
```

Now the question is, what is 1280 in my code.

Answer is this is nothing but the width of the design that the designer provides. E.x. If the designer gives a design of size 1080x1920, you can replace 1280 with 1080.

So if a designer has a font of 55 in the design, we can use 55 as below.

```
applyFont(titleTV, 55f);
```

### This works for both orientations...