# Subtracting float in android gives me larger number

Tags: android, floating-point, onclick, subtraction

I cannot figure this one out, but I cannot seem to get android to ever cooperate with simple math. I have created a ZoomControls that changes text size of a TextView. Seems simple. I increase the font size no problem. Subtracting just adds it for some weird reason.

```
zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       float val = songtext.getTextSize();
       float test = (val - 1);
       songtext.setTextSize(test);
    }
});
```

Judging by this simple code, the font size should be subtracted by 1 everytime the button is pressed. Instead it increases by 1. ??? I am ripping my hair out.

Comment: What's the text size's value?

Comment: Did you try to print values before and after subtraction?

Comment: The textsize value from the xml file is 20dp, however the text.gettextsize() methods returns a float of 30.0, this is apparently in pixels. I can't figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The difference here is that in the setTextSize(int size) method, the
>   unit type by default is "sp" or "scaled pixels". This value will be a
>   different pixel dimension for each screen density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi).
>
> getTextSize(), on the other hand, returns the actual pixel dimensions
>   of the text.
>
> You can use setTextSize(int unit, int size) to specify a unit type.
>   The values for this can be found in the TypedValue class, but some of
>   them are:
>
> TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX : Pixels
>
> TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP : Scaled Pixels
>
> TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP : Device Independent Pixels

As explained at [TextView.setTextSize behaves abnormally - How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally) by kcoppock

I simply used the below:

`textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,size + increaseTextBy);`