# fit the text on different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, html

[this is the picture with same text size on 5inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcqs7.png)

[this is the picture with same textsize on 4inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Slv.png)

I want the text in the Text View to fit on different screen sizes depending on their fonts. I have used html for the text.

Here's my strings.xml

```
<string name="seven">
<![CDATA[
<h1>श्रीज्ञानदेवाची आरती</h1>

<body>आरती ज्ञानराजा॥<br>
महाकैवल्यतेजा॥<br>
सेविती साधुसंत ॥<br>
मनु वेधला माझा ॥ ध्रु० ॥<br>
लोपलें ज्ञान जगीं ॥<br>
हित नेणती कोणी ॥<br>   
अवतार पांडुरंग ॥<br>
नाम ठेविलें ज्ञानी ॥ आरती ॥ १ ॥<br>
कनकांचे ताट करीं ॥<br>
उभ्या गोपिका नारी ॥<br>
नारद तुंबरु ही ॥<br>
साम गायन करी ॥ आरती० ॥ २ ॥<br>
प्रगट गुह्य बोले ॥<br>
विश्व ब्रह्मची केलें ॥<br>
रामा जनार्दनीं ॥<br>
चरणी मस्तक ठेविले ॥ आरती० ॥ ३ ॥<br>
<br>
<br>
<br></body>]]>
```

activity.xml

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:id="@+id/textView15"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

activity.java

```
tv15=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
tv15.setTextSize((float)23.5);
tv15.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.seven)));
```

Comment: what is problem you are facing ?

Comment: the text gets properly fit on 5 inch screen.....whereas there is problem when put on 4inch screen  phone.....the text in the text view does not fit on it....means some lines come on the next line.....

Comment: check the images N J

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884091/dynamic-text-size-change-according-to-tablet this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Following way may helps you.

Define some size in `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="textSize">15sp</dimen>
```

then in Java, `setTextSize` like,

```
int txtsize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.textSize);
tv15.setTextSize(txtsize);
```

this will give same sizes of all devices.

Comment: that doesnt solve my question......the problem is that the text gets properly fit on 5 inch screen.....whereas there is problem when put on 4inch screen phone.....the text in the text view does not fit on it....means some lines come on the next line.....

Comment: kindly check the images Sathish Kumar J

Comment: refer this link may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes

Answer (score 0):

You have set fix pixel size here

**tv15.setTextSize((float)23.5);**

So it getting same size for all screen.

Solution1. Take text size in dp in xml

**android:textSize="18dp"**

Solution2. Take different dimention file for different screen size.

```
value-mdpi/dimen.xml
<dimen name="hindi_text_size">15dp</dimen>

value-hdpi/dimen.xml
<dimen name="hindi_text_size">18dp</dimen>
```

in xml now use this parameter

**android:textSize="@dimen/hindi_text_size"**