# Strange behaviour when reuse the text size of TextView

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I want to scale my `textview` font size, however, I could not understand its behavior from very simple code so I cannot control the font size.

```
 TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
 textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());
```

The font size was supposed not to change, but the `textView` changed its font size while I used the same value from getTextSize() method. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference here is that in the setTextSize(int size) method, the
>   unit type by default is "sp" or "scaled pixels". This value will be a
>   different pixel dimension for each screen density (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi).
>
> getTextSize(), on the other hand, returns the actual pixel dimensions
>   of the text.

It also explains your issue. The full thread link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally-how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynam)

If you want to convert them then:

```
public static float pixel2Sp(Context context, float px) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}

textView.setTextSize(pixel2Sp(context, textView.getTextSize());
```

Comment: Thanks. So I can scale with      textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textView.getTextSize()*scale);