# Programming zoom conrol button

Tags: controls, zooming, android-studio-2.1

How to program this zoom control for zoom in and zoom out? But I want zoom text (not picture). Is it possible to zooming text? In internet all people zooming picture.. But is not the same than text.

[image]

Comment: You can control the zooming in and out of the text by setting the size of he the text.

Comment: @SurendraSingh Can you explain? I want to zoom text in app after use button which I have on the screen :/

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally-how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynam

if you have some kind of textview in your android app. Then using the above feature you can show the zoom effect by changing the text size in the text view.

Comment: I don't understand that... Where I must paste that code? When I paste to anything.java I have a lot of errors.. :/