# Button for editing TextView size, style

Tags: java, android

I want to make buttons to adjust my text. There are buttons for making the TextView bigger, smaller, back and forth between italic and bold.

I want to edit the TextView called "text"

In the code below, when I clicked the "butBig" or "butSmall" button, both button does the same thing it makes my text size increase but not by 5, it became really big. When I clicked on either button again, the TextView disappear like it is too big for the frame.

```
butBig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float size = text.getTextSize();
            text.setTextSize(size + 5.0F);

        }
    });

    butSmall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float size = text.getTextSize();
            text.setTextSize(size - 5.0F);

        }
    });
```

For Italic and Bold, my code here does work but sometimes when I clicked either of these buttons, the app crashed for no reason..

```
butItalic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.ITALIC) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.NORMAL) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            }


        }
    });


    butBold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.ITALIC) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.NORMAL) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            } else if (text.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) {

                text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

            }


        }
    });
```

Please help me with this

Thank you

Edit: Here's my logcat :)

> --------- beginning of crash
>   11-05 05:34:17.581 2416-2416/com.example.textadjust E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.example.textadjust, PID: 2416
>                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Typeface.getStyle()' on a null object reference
>                                                                            at com.example.textadjust.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   11-05 05:34:19.734 2416-2416/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2416 SIG: 9

Comment: Your question is good! show the logs for the crash first! from the logcat!

Comment: logcat added Thank you :D

Comment: I have edited my answer check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should know so far is that the Size of TextSize your are doing using the method:

```
text.setTextSize(size + 5.0F);
```

The size units is Scalled Pixels and if you are wondering or want to use the size in `dp` here is the method to change pixels to `dp`:

```
public int getDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

Add this method in your clas for that! But alternatively (**I recommend**)  you can use the method:

```
setTextSize(int unit, float size);
```

Where the parameter `int unit` here i can take values like as given by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally-how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynam#answers):

```
TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX   //Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP   //Scaled Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP  //Device Independent Pixels
```

And for the other question add some logs for the crash! to figure out what might be the error and I will edit my answer to add that!!

But my suggestion so far reduce the conditions and use a `switch` instead of `if` and `else`s and make sure the `TextView` has a text before calling those methods. Add some logs to be sure whats going on!

**EDIT FOR THE CRASH**
As I guessed the cause for the crash is `NullPointerException`. Which may be caused by your variable of `TextView` being `null`. Possible causes is it is not assigned just in `onCreate()` or it has no text to display when assigned (I guess).
*SOLUTION*:
Because you are going to use the `TextView` in your whole class declare it as a class variable and assign it `onCreate` if its `Activity` or `onCreateView` if `Fragment`:
Just inside your class before any method:

```
private TextView text;
```

Then inside `onCreate` assign it as:

```
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id); //Replace with a real id
```

And set a  default text or `Typeface` in `xml` or in `java` code. Now you can access the `TextView` variable everywhere in the class it will not be `null`.

And as a tip again for performance and readability use `switch` instead of `if` and `else`.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and comment if you still get some errors! @Triniel

Comment: I already used text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id); it doesn't work :( I still get the same NullPointerException. Thanks for the text size, it works perfectly!! Also, do you have any way to limit the font size when I increase it,?

Comment: You will have to do that `onCreate` and also do `text.setText("anything");` and try something like `text.setTypeface(something);` in the same `onCreate` the issue is to make some default properties you cant get the typeface if it is not set yet or textview has no size!

Comment: Oh for the issue of limiting the font size or text size is using the the method `text.getTextSize()` the compare with your current size before increasing but it will return the value in `pixels` and use it to compare if the limit is exceeded before increasing. You can do the same in limiting down!

Comment: You can reply anytime!

Comment: I did use `text.getTextSize()` before but I didn't know it is in pixels, Thank you so much :)

Comment: Oooh that's a it @Triniel all the best **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: I changed all my if-else to `switch (text.getTypeface().getStyle()) {

                    case (Typeface.BOLD):
                        text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);` It doesn't work :( Is this the proper way of doing it?

Comment: It should work but may be there is an error somewhere else! that is the correct way of doing it!

Comment: If you find a number of errors in that way there may be something or just go back to `if` and `else` if you cant see the problem!

Comment: Ctrl+Z or Cmd+Z

Comment: Thank you so muchh !! :You're the best :D

Comment: Okay thank you too @Triniel **Happy Coding!** again!