# How do you set multiple textviews to do the same thing when clicked? Android Studios

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a an android app with multiple textviews that when clicked can change a property of the textview such as font size. I wanted to know if there was a way to do this with one onclick method and only one onclick listener. I have the android:onClick="Click" set to a click function for all the text views.

Comment: To answer your question keep a list of all your TextViews and update them in your `Click()` method.  However, if you only want to change a cosmetic trait like using a larger font size for your entire app, you should use Themes.

Comment: I meant changing the font size of just the textview that was clicked. I know there is a generic way of doing this using the view that is passed into to the click method. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add `android:onClick="onClick"` to all textviews
Then in your activity

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   public void onClick(View view) {
       if (view instanceOf TextView) {
           ((TextView)view).setTextSize(14);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not make it `if (view instanceof TextView) { … }` That way you make it “safe”.

Answer (score 0):

> changing the font size of just the textview that was clicked

See [setTextSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%20float)):

```
public void Click(View v) {
    ((TextView) v).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16); 
}
```

Be wary of using `getTextSize()` to set the new text size: [TextView.setTextSize behaves abnormally - How to set text size of textview dynamically for different screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687065/textview-settextsize-behaves-abnormally-how-to-set-text-size-of-textview-dynam)